# Would you use operator && instead of if?

Tags: conditional-statements

Which way is more clear to write this specific type of a condition?

```
if (result) result = await DoTask();
return result;
```

Or:

```
return result && await DoTask();
```

Comment: By the way, to the guys who downvoted - I know that this question is subjective and SO isn't really a place for questions like these ;) But tell me where can I ask questions like these then, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

my humble opinion is that using if is much more explicit and easier to read, but I would also suggest you to use the more verbatim style, i.e.:

```
if (result)
{
    result = await DoTask();
}

return result;
```

Making an if statement inline with the code block that should be executed on true is a bit perplexing at first look. Just according to me ...

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance, it should be no difference. In terms of readability, my personal opinion is that "if" is more readable.